# Losing data on fragment change

Tags: android, fragment, tabview

Can you help me on this problem.

I have a Activity with a bottom navigation bar which change the fragment in the middle. One of the option is to show a list of itens divided in 2 groups using tabs.
On the first time I open the fragment all data are there as expected but one I change the fragment and call a newInstance of the fragment with the list again, all data is gone. Please see the GIF bellow for better understand:

[image]

Here are the code to set the tabs:

```
 private void setViewPager(){
        List<Fragment> frag = new ArrayList<>();
        frag.add(MyReservationsFragment.newInstance(true));
        frag.add(MyReservationsFragment.newInstance(false));

        MyViewPagerAdapter myViewPagerAdapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(), frag, getContext());
        vpaReservations.setAdapter(myViewPagerAdapter);
        tabReservations.addTab(tabReservations.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.s_tab_1)));
        tabReservations.addTab(tabReservations.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.s_tab_2)));
        tabReservations.setupWithViewPager(vpaReservations);
    }
```

And here are how I instantiate each fragment:

```
public class MyReservationsFragment extends Fragment implements MyReservationsContract.View{

    private static final String TAG = "MyResFrag";
    private static final String ONLY_PENDING = "onlyPending";
    private static final String RESERVATION_ID = "reservationId";

    @BindView(R.id.rvi_my_reservations) protected RecyclerView rviMyReservations;

    private boolean onlyPending;
    private MyReservationsContract.Presenter mPresenter;


    public MyReservationsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static MyReservationsFragment newInstance(boolean onlyPending) {
        MyReservationsFragment frag = new MyReservationsFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putBoolean(ONLY_PENDING, onlyPending);
        frag.setArguments(args);

        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            onlyPending = getArguments().getBoolean(ONLY_PENDING);
        }

        mPresenter=new MyReservationsPresenter();

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_reservations_list, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
//        List<MyReservation> myReservations = Const.getMyReservations(onlyPending);

        List<Reservation> myReservations = mPresenter.getUserReservationsByStatus(onlyPending);
        setRecyclerView(myReservations);
    }

    private void setRecyclerView(final List<Reservation> myReservations){
        rviMyReservations.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        rviMyReservations.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        MyReservationAdapter mAdapter = new MyReservationAdapter(myReservations,getContext());
        mAdapter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int position = rviMyReservations.getChildLayoutPosition(view);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ReservationDetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(RESERVATION_ID, myReservations.get(position).getId());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        rviMyReservations.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        rviMyReservations.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    }


}
```

I already tried to save the flag of "onlyPending" variable but as the fragment is not get destroyed it has the same behaviour. I am stuck on this for 2 days already, can you guys help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Dont create instance using new operator everytime, new object of fragment will be created and old data will be gone. so create like this,

first in fragment class:

```
  public static  MyReservationsFragment frag;
```

in newInstance Method:

```
public static MyReservationsFragment newInstance(boolean onlyPending) {
    if(frag == null)
    {
         frag = new MyReservationsFragment();
    }

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putBoolean(ONLY_PENDING, onlyPending);
    frag.setArguments(args);

    return frag;
}
```